# Let's Encrypt Certbot and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, ssl, heroku, deployment

Certbot has this section in the beginning where I have to specify
"My HTTP website is running **(web server)  on **(system it's running on )"

I use Google Domain for my domain and heroku to deploy. I'm using Django.
After a bit of research I found out that my website is runing on a gunicorn webserver. In this case, which one should I select on the Software? They have Apache, Nginx, Haproxy, Plesk, Web hosting product, none of the above. Also How can I find out which system my webdite is runing on?
Thank you in advance. Any advice is appreciated.

I'm aware that if I upgrade my heroku to a padiu version it's easier but I want to do it for free. I got my account verrified.

Comment: You can't do that - gunicorn is your wsgi server, not your web server. Your web server is provided by Heroku and you have to provision SSL through Heroku.

Comment: @solarissmoke but when I inspect my site using google dev tool it says gunicorn. Does that means it’s running wsgi server provided by heroku?